# PostgreSQL, Group by values

Tags: postgresql

I have situation where i should get summed results of two groups depend on column values. Here is short example of used table and query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytemptable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytemptable(
    id          integer PRIMARY KEY,
    cat         text,
    val         decimal);

INSERT INTO mytemptable VALUES
               ( 1, ' ',  10),    
               ( 5, 'n',  4.2),
               ( 6, 'p', 15),
               ( 7, 'd', 10), --added
               ( 9, '',  10),
               (11, null, 2.3),
               (14, 'p',  4.16);

SELECT cat, SUM(val) FROM mytemptable
 GROUP BY cat
 ORDER BY cat;
```

... which gives such result:

```
"";10
" ";10
"d";10
"n";4.2
"p";19.16
"";2.3
```

From this code I would need to get summed only two groups. One from cat='p' and second from all other cat's.
Is something like that possible to get with group by/having or similar in one pass. Something like GROUP BY cat='p', cat IN('', ' ', 'n', null). Maybe here can be more than two wanted conditions.
If it is please show me how.

Wanted result for this case will be:

```
    "p";19.14 (summed val from cat 'p')
    "d";10    (summed val from cat 'd') --added
    " ";26.5  (summed val from other cat's than 'p' and 'd')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may group using a `CASE` expression, which buckets all `p` category records together, and all other non `p` records together:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN cat = 'p' THEN 'p' ELSE ' ' END AS cat,
    SUM(val)
FROM mytemptable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN cat = 'p' THEN 'p' ELSE ' ' END
ORDER BY cat DESC;
```

[image]

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you need more buckets, then just add more levels to the `CASE` expression, e.g. to your updated question use this:

```
CASE WHEN cat = 'p' THEN 'p'
     WHEN cat = 'd' THEN 'd'
     ELSE ' ' END
```

Comment: That works, but what will happen if some third cat involves here?

Comment: Um....add more levels to the `CASE` expression?  I can't really answer your question, because I don't know what you have in mind.

Comment: `SELECT
    CASE WHEN cat = 'p' THEN 'p' WHEN cat ='n' THEN 'n' ELSE ' ' END AS scat,
    SUM(val)
FROM mytemptable
GROUP BY scat
ORDER BY scat DESC;` maybe?

Comment: I addapted example something if you don't mind for better undarstanding. Here would be needed a sum for cat='p', cat='d' and third from all other cat's.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I understand now. It works for a few cats. That's what I'm asking for.

Comment: @S-Man Yes, that's shorter, but the point of my `CASE` expression was to show how the syntax allows the creation of _more_ than two buckets.  If the OP wanted to map more than one `cat` to the `p` bucket, your suggestion could not be used.

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9420e0c2e3c81a53def22db33bb757f1)

I would "convert" the `cat` value in a subquery (or CTE). Then you only need one `CASE` clause.

```
SELECT
    cat,
    SUM(val)
FROM (
    SELECT
        val,
        CASE WHEN cat IN ('p') THEN cat ELSE ' ' END as cat
    FROM
        mytable
) s
GROUP BY
    cat
```

CTE Version:

```
WITH new_cat AS (
    SELECT
        val,
        CASE WHEN cat IN ('p') THEN cat ELSE ' ' END as cat
    FROM
        mytable
)
SELECT
    cat,
    SUM(val)
FROM 
    new_cat
GROUP BY
    cat
```

---

Then you are able to expand your list with every value you need:

```
SELECT
    cat,
    SUM(val)
FROM (
    SELECT
        val,
        CASE WHEN cat IN ('p', 'd') THEN cat ELSE ' ' END as cat
    FROM
        mytable
) s
GROUP BY
    cat
```

**Result:**

```
cat   sum
d     10 
p     19.16
      22.3
```

Comment: Thanks S-Man. Now we have subquery what gives good result but it is not wanted.

Comment: Why? Is the result wrong? If you want it without Subquery, use a CTE (added above))

Comment: I wouldn't use a subquery here, because it will slow down performance, perhaps by a lot, and it also doesn't make the query easier to read.

Comment: You are right in all. But I was able to use subquery by myself. I ask this question to learn something new and maybe simpler. Actually, I was hoping that Group by have some trick to group by value/conditions...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the sub-query (derived table) will not affect performance in any way. The CTE might though

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The `WITH` seems slower than your version but the subselect seems a little faster than your solution. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b2c532ad6f06cb6b2733a611bff5b585

Comment: @S-Man I didn't know this about Postgres, apologies.  But keep in mind that in most other databases subqueries usually aren't good if you can avoid them :-)